# google Analytics API: IN List with REGEX

Tags: python, api, google-analytics

I have a large list of 5k+ items of a certain dimension attribute. 
Due to an inefficient setup of our web traffic, I need to call the google Analytics API and get page View information on the set that matches all these attributes. 
Unfornately, these attributes are not matched directly in any dimension, so I would need to partially match the string using regex. That works on a few examples, but is not feasible for 5k arguments.

Inversely, for a direct match I would use the APIs *IN_LIST* operator, but that is then also not possible.

Does anyone have any leads on how to approach this? Can I force the *IN_LIST* operator to match with regex? Or is this simply not possible?

**Example**:

gAnalytics string:

- www.test.com/something-written-here-4561
- www.me.com/something-different-4561-written here

Search argument: ["4561"]

My code: (the code works like a charm, it's more a question how this should be handled with REGEX and the IN_LIST operator)

```py
    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests':[
                {
                    'viewId': sViewID
                    , "pageSize": 100000
                    , "samplingLevel": "LARGE"
                    , 'dateRanges': [{'startDate':'2020-05-01', 'endDate':'2020-05-31'}]
                    , 'metrics': [{'expression': metric} for metric in lMetrics]
                    , 'dimensions': [{'name': name} for name in lDimensions]
                    , "dimensionFilterClauses": [{
                        "operator": "AND"
                        , "filters": [{"dimensionName": item.get("dimName"), "operator": item.get("operator"), "expressions": item.get("value")} for key,item in lFilters.items()]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ).execute()
```

and the filters:

```py
lFilters = {

    1: {
       "dimName":"ga:pagePath"
       , "operator": "IN_LIST"
       , "value":  lIDs[0]
    } 
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your expression.
Like this:

```
# ['regular_a', 'regular_b'] # IN_LIST
'regular_a|regular_b' # REGEXP
```